# Loop through text file using date search using sed or awk

Tags: awk, sed

Hello sed and awk experts am trying to loop through a log file with contents below while using date time search.
I would like to loop between `2021/08/09 11:18:10` and `2021/08/09 10:49:32`
The date format is `YYYY/MM/DD`

```
2021/08/09 10:22:24 202108091022G5a Outbound text with ref number 2
2021/08/09 10:31:44 202108091031GhG Outbound text with ref number 3
2021/08/09 10:31:51 202108091031KZL Outbound text with ref number 4
2021/08/09 10:49:32 2021080910496ZT Outbound text with ref number 5
2021/08/09 11:02:27 2021080911025eQ Outbound text with ref number 6
2021/08/09 11:14:28 202108091114Aim Outbound text with ref number 6
2021/08/09 11:15:13 202108091115bRi Outbound text with ref number 7
2021/08/09 11:17:11 202108091117KIK Outbound text with ref number 8
2021/08/09 11:18:10 202108091118dB5 Outbound text with ref number 9
2021/08/09 11:18:17 202108091118qxN Outbound text with ref number 10
2021/08/09 11:19:28 202108091119TuI Outbound text with ref number 11
```

I tried mine below but it's returning errors

```
sed -n '/2021/08/09 09:00:00/,/2021/08/09 11:00:00/p'  Desktop/smslog.log
sed: -e expression #1, char 7: unknown command: `0'
```

Comment: Your error is because that you're using: `/2021/08/09...`, while you should define that `/` between numbers isn't a special character using `\/`: `.../2021\/08\/09 09:00:00/...`.

Comment: `sed` is probably not the best tool for this. If you have GNU `awk` you could give it a try: the `mktime` extension converts date/time strings to timestamps that can then be compared numerically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk -v beg='2021/08/09 09:00:00' -v end='2021/08/09 11:00:00' '
    {cur=$1" "$2} (beg<=cur) && (cur<=end)
' file
2021/08/09 10:22:24 202108091022G5a Outbound text with ref number 2
2021/08/09 10:31:44 202108091031GhG Outbound text with ref number 3
2021/08/09 10:31:51 202108091031KZL Outbound text with ref number 4
2021/08/09 10:49:32 2021080910496ZT Outbound text with ref number 5
```

or more efficiently but a bit less clearly:

```
$ awk -v beg='2021/08/09 09:00:00' -v end='2021/08/09 11:00:00' '
    {cur=$1" "$2} cur>end{exit} beg<=cur
' file
```

You don't need GNU awk for time functions for this, all you need is a simple string comparison of the timestamps.

The reason not to try to use `sed` with a range expression for this is that that would require the specific timestamps used in the date command to be present in the input file (i.e. it can only support a `==` comparison) whereas with awk you can use `>=` for the start and `>` for the end to get timestamps within the range without those specific timestamps having to be present.

Comment: Thanks very much. Your solution is precise and its accurate in giving results I expected

Answer (score 4):

#### First mistake

In searching and expressions we have something named special characters, like `/`, `*`, ... that to use them in normal mode, you'll need to add `\` in the start: `\/`, `\*`, `\...`.

In conclusion, this code is wrong:

```sh
$ sed -n '/2021/08/09 09:00:00/,/2021/08/09 11:00:00/p' Desktop/smslog.log
```

Correct syntax:

```sh
$ sed -n '\#^2021/08/09 10:#,\#^2021/08/09 11:#p' Desktop/smslog.log
```

- In this code we used a different format from my original post that *Ed* suggested, but you get the idea.

#### Second mistake

Your `sed -n` command will only look upto specified lines that contain exactly your `BEGIN`/`END`, but in this query, we don't have any log exactly for `2021\/08\/09 09:00:00`, so this doesn't show you anything because it doesn't find that log to start and end with your `END` point.

For example you can do this to get every `11:--:--` to `11:--:--` messages:

```sh
$ sed -n '\#^2021/08/09 11:#,\#^2021/08/09 11:#p' Desktop/smslog.log
2021/08/09 11:02:27 2021080911025eQ Outbound text with ref number 6
2021/08/09 11:14:28 202108091114Aim Outbound text with ref number 6
2021/08/09 11:15:13 202108091115bRi Outbound text with ref number 7
2021/08/09 11:17:11 202108091117KIK Outbound text with ref number 8
2021/08/09 11:18:10 202108091118dB5 Outbound text with ref number 9
2021/08/09 11:18:17 202108091118qxN Outbound text with ref number 10
2021/08/09 11:19:28 202108091119TuI Outbound text with ref number 11

$ sed -n '\#^2021/08/09 10:#,\#^2021/08/09 10:#p' Desktop/smslog.log
2021/08/09 10:22:24 202108091022G5a Outbound text with ref number 2
2021/08/09 10:31:44 202108091031GhG Outbound text with ref number 3
2021/08/09 10:31:51 202108091031KZL Outbound text with ref number 4
2021/08/09 10:49:32 2021080910496ZT Outbound text with ref number 5

$ sed -n '\#^2021/08/09 10:#,\#^2021/08/09 11:#p' Desktop/smslog.log
2021/08/09 10:22:24 202108091022G5a Outbound text with ref number 2
2021/08/09 10:31:44 202108091031GhG Outbound text with ref number 3
2021/08/09 10:31:51 202108091031KZL Outbound text with ref number 4
2021/08/09 10:49:32 2021080910496ZT Outbound text with ref number 5
2021/08/09 11:02:27 2021080911025eQ Outbound text with ref number 6
2021/08/09 11:14:28 202108091114Aim Outbound text with ref number 6
2021/08/09 11:15:13 202108091115bRi Outbound text with ref number 7
2021/08/09 11:17:11 202108091117KIK Outbound text with ref number 8
2021/08/09 11:18:10 202108091118dB5 Outbound text with ref number 9
2021/08/09 11:18:17 202108091118qxN Outbound text with ref number 10
2021/08/09 11:19:28 202108091119TuI Outbound text with ref number 11
```

Answer (score 3):

`sed` is probably not the best tool for this. If you have GNU `awk` you could give it a try: the `mktime` extension converts date/time strings to timestamps that can then be compared numerically:

```
$ cat foo.awk
function d2t(d) { gsub(/(\/|:)/," ",d); return mktime(d,1); }
BEGIN { a=d2t(x); b=d2t(y); }
{ d=d2t($1 " " $2); }
d>=a && d<=b
```

The `d2t` function does the conversion of your date/time strings (considered as in UTC zone to avoid DTS shifts) to UNIX timestamps. It first replaces the `/` and `:` characters by spaces with `gsub`.

Pass your start and stop date/times as the `x` and `y` variables. Demo:

```
$ awk -f foo.awk -v x="2021/08/09 09:00:00" -v y="2021/08/09 11:00:00" data.txt
2021/08/09 10:22:24 202108091022G5a Outbound text with ref number 2
2021/08/09 10:31:44 202108091031GhG Outbound text with ref number 3
2021/08/09 10:31:51 202108091031KZL Outbound text with ref number 4
2021/08/09 10:49:32 2021080910496ZT Outbound text with ref number 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Better using `awk` to get more flexibility (`GNU awk`):

```
$ awk -F[/:[:blank:]] 'BEGIN{start=mktime("2021 08 09 09 00 00");end=mktime("2021 08 09 11 00 00")} {t=mktime($1 " " $2 " " $3 " " $4 " " $5 " " $6)} t>start && t<end' file.txt
2021/08/09 10:22:24 202108091022G5a Outbound text with ref number 2
2021/08/09 10:31:44 202108091031GhG Outbound text with ref number 3
2021/08/09 10:31:51 202108091031KZL Outbound text with ref number 4
2021/08/09 10:49:32 2021080910496ZT Outbound text with ref number 5
$ awk -F[/:[:blank:]] 'BEGIN{start=mktime("2021 08 09 10 40 00");end=mktime("2021 08 09 11 20 00")} {t=mktime($1 " " $2 " " $3 " " $4 " " $5 " " $6)} t>start && t<end' file.txt
2021/08/09 10:49:32 2021080910496ZT Outbound text with ref number 5
2021/08/09 11:02:27 2021080911025eQ Outbound text with ref number 6
2021/08/09 11:14:28 202108091114Aim Outbound text with ref number 6
2021/08/09 11:15:13 202108091115bRi Outbound text with ref number 7
2021/08/09 11:17:11 202108091117KIK Outbound text with ref number 8
2021/08/09 11:18:10 202108091118dB5 Outbound text with ref number 9
2021/08/09 11:18:17 202108091118qxN Outbound text with ref number 10
2021/08/09 11:19:28 202108091119TuI Outbound text with ref number 11
```

By using `mktime` to get and compare the timestamps, you can specify whatever range you want.

Break the lines to make it clearer:

```
awk -F[/:[:blank:]] '
    BEGIN{start=mktime("2021 08 09 09 00 00");
    end=mktime("2021 08 09 11 00 00")} 
    {t=mktime($1 " " $2 " " $3 " " $4 " " $5 " " $6)} 
    t>start && t<end' file.txt

awk -F[/:[:blank:]] '
    BEGIN{start=mktime("2021 08 09 10 40 00");
    end=mktime("2021 08 09 11 20 00")} 
    {t=mktime($1 " " $2 " " $3 " " $4 " " $5 " " $6)}
     t>start && t<end' file.txt
```